# OpenVPN client change hostname resolving in Windows 2003 Server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, routing, openvpn

I have OpenVPN client at Windows server 2003 and OpenVPN works right. 
Also I have 1C service there.
Also I have stopped and have deleted Routing and Remote Access Role for Windows server 2003 (and Server was rebooted of course).

**So here is a problem:**
When my OpenVPN client have started - my servername's name server.company.local resolved **10.8.8.105** instead of normal **192.168.34.10**. As result the access to my 1C service stops.

Here are my **route print** before and after OpenVPN client connection:

```
Сетевой адрес           Маска сети      Адрес шлюза       Интерфейс  Метрика
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.34.15    192.168.34.10     10
       10.10.10.0    255.255.255.0      10.10.10.10      10.10.10.10     10
      10.10.10.10  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1        127.0.0.1     10
   10.255.255.255  255.255.255.255      10.10.10.10      10.10.10.10     10
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0        127.0.0.1        127.0.0.1      1
     192.168.34.0    255.255.255.0    192.168.34.10    192.168.34.10     10
    192.168.34.10  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1        127.0.0.1     10
   192.168.34.255  255.255.255.255    192.168.34.10    192.168.34.10     10
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0      10.10.10.10      10.10.10.10     10
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0    192.168.34.10    192.168.34.10     10
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255      10.10.10.10      10.10.10.10      1
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255      10.10.10.10            10005      1
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255    192.168.34.10    192.168.34.10      1
Основной шлюз:       192.168.34.15
===========================================================================
Постоянные маршруты:
  Отсутствует


Активные маршруты:
Сетевой адрес           Маска сети      Адрес шлюза       Интерфейс  Метрика
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.34.15    192.168.34.10     10
         10.8.8.0    255.255.255.0       10.8.8.106       10.8.8.105      1
       10.8.8.104  255.255.255.252       10.8.8.105       10.8.8.105     30
       10.8.8.105  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1        127.0.0.1     30
       10.10.10.0    255.255.255.0      10.10.10.10      10.10.10.10     10
      10.10.10.10  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1        127.0.0.1     10
   10.255.255.255  255.255.255.255       10.8.8.105       10.8.8.105     30
   10.255.255.255  255.255.255.255      10.10.10.10      10.10.10.10     10
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0        127.0.0.1        127.0.0.1      1
     192.168.34.0    255.255.255.0    192.168.34.10    192.168.34.10     10
    192.168.34.10  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1        127.0.0.1     10
   192.168.34.255  255.255.255.255    192.168.34.10    192.168.34.10     10
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0       10.8.8.105       10.8.8.105     30
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0      10.10.10.10      10.10.10.10     10
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0    192.168.34.10    192.168.34.10     10
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255       10.8.8.105       10.8.8.105      1
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255      10.10.10.10      10.10.10.10      1
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255    192.168.34.10    192.168.34.10      1
Основной шлюз:       192.168.34.15
===========================================================================
Постоянные маршруты:
  Отсутствует
```

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Windows is setting the address of the VPN interface in the DNS. Sometimes this is desirable, for a server it is not.

In the registry, you can set

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\DisableDynamicUpdate=1
```

If you want to keep the dynamic update on other interfaces, find the subentry of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters` for the VPN interface and set `DisableDynamicUpdate=1` there.

Comment: It works until server rebooting... I think OpenVPN connection starts first...

Comment: That is strange. I use this setting, and the effect is persistent.

Comment: I did it! Works! I have just changed interface order, I pulled OpenVPN connection a litle bit lower here: Control Panel -> Network Connections -> Advanced -> Adapters and Bindings -> Connections